# Retraining CNN with new data leads to error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

- tf 2.9.0
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Python 3.9.5
- CUDA/cuDNN version: cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29920130_0
- GPU model and memory: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB

Whenever i want to retrain my already trained Unet-CNN with new data, I get an error, see below
I trained my unet like this:

```
    files = glob.glob(f'{args.p_data}/*.h5')
    val_files = glob.glob(f'{args.p_val}/*.h5')
    s=(120,100,50,1)
    spe = int(np.floor(len(files) / args.bs))
    vspe = int(np.floor(len(val_files)/ args.bs))
    
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(pygen.generator, args=[files,minmax],output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[0], dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[1], dtype=tf.float32)))

    val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(pygen.generator, args=[val_files,minmax],output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[0], dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[1], dtype=tf.float32)))


    dataset = dataset.take(len(files)).cache().batch(args.bs).repeat(args.ep).prefetch(10) #CACHE DATA FROM SCRATCH
    val_dataset = val_dataset.take(len(val_files)).cache(filename=f'{tempfile.gettempdir()}/val').batch(128).repeat(args.ep).prefetch(10)
    
    strategy = tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
    with strategy.scope():
        m = unet28.build(s[0])
        m.fit(dataset,validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=args.ep, steps_per_epoch = spe,validation_steps = vspe,callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback,save50,model_csv_logger,model_tensorboard,model_earlystopping_30],verbose=2)
```

Unet:

```
def double(x, n_filters):
    x = Conv3D(n_filters, 3, padding = "same", activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv3D(n_filters, 3, padding = "same", activation='relu')(x)
    return x

def encode(x, n_filters,dropout):
    f = double(x, n_filters)
    p = Conv3D(n_filters, 3 , strides= 2 ,activation='relu', padding='same')(f)
    if dropout == True:
        p = layers.Dropout(0.2)(p)
    return f, p

def decode(x, conv_features, n_filters,dropout):
    x = Conv3DTranspose(n_filters, 3, 2, activation='relu', padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.concatenate([x, conv_features])
    # x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    if dropout == True:
        x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = double(x, n_filters)
    return x

def build(input_shape):
    input = Input(input_shape)
    padding = utils.tuplePadding(input_shape[:-1],4)
    print(padding)
    input_padded = ZeroPadding3D(padding)(input)

    f1, p1 = encode(input_padded, 32, False)
    f2, p2 = encode(p1, 64, False)
    f3, p3 = encode(p2, 128,False)
    f4, p4 = encode(p3, 256,False)

    bottleneck = double(p4, 512)

    u6 = decode(bottleneck, f4, 256, False)
    u7 = decode(u6, f3, 128,False)
    u8 = decode(u7, f2, 64,False)
    u9 = decode(u8, f1, 32,False)

    outputs = Conv3D(6, 1, padding="same", activation="linear")(u9)
    outputs = Cropping3D(cropping=(padding))(outputs)
    model = Model(input, outputs, name="unet28")
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='mean_absolute_error')
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Whenever I want to load the saved model like this and use the same code for the datasets as above:

```
    saved_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(args.p_model)
    saved_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='mean_absolute_error')
    saved_model.fit(dataset,validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=args.ep, steps_per_epoch = spe,validation_steps = vspe,callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback,save50,model_csv_logger,model_earlystopping_30],verbose=2)
```

I get following error:

```
Failed to allocate memory for convolution redzone checking; skipping this check. This is benign and only means that we won't check cudnn for out-of-bounds reads and writes. This message will only be printed once.
2023-07-09 17:37:19.863891: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8201
2023-07-09 17:37:32.696577: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:479] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 7.00GiB (rounded to 7516192768)requested by op unet28/conv3d_1/Conv3D
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2023-07-09 17:37:32.696633: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1027] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2023-07-09 17:37:32.696654: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (256):  ...
2023-07-09 17:37:32.699876: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] Stats: 
Limit:                     10109976576
InUse:                      9024100864
MaxInUse:                   9223163904
NumAllocs:                         586
MaxAllocSize:               7516192768
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2023-07-09 17:37:32.699903: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:491] *******_______*************************************************************************************_
2023-07-09 17:37:32.699973: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_3d.cc:186 : RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,32,128,112,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/l/l_schu38/ba-lukas/modelmain.py", line 212, in <module>
    saved_model.fit(dataset,validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=args.ep, steps_per_epoch = spe,validation_steps = vspe,callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback,save50,model_csv_logger,model_earlystopping_30],verbose=2)
  File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'unet28/conv3d_1/Conv3D' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/ba-lukas/modelmain.py", line 212, in <module>
      saved_model.fit(dataset,validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=args.ep, steps_per_epoch = spe,validation_steps = vspe,callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback,save50,model_csv_logger,model_earlystopping_30],verbose=2)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 458, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 250, in call
      outputs = self.convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    File "/home/l/l_schu38/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 225, in convolution_op
      return tf.nn.convolution(
Node: 'unet28/conv3d_1/Conv3D'
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,32,128,112,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node unet28/conv3d_1/Conv3D}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_8292]
2023-07-09 17:37:36.332325: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

I don't understand why the error occurs, since everything is the same as it was in the very first training?

Comment: I misread some parts of the error. Is there something that prevents you from using the whole GPU (because of the 10GB Limit in the error message). You could try smaller_batch sizes until it fits and use `nvidia-smi` to check the memory usage in a separate shell.

Answer (score 0):

You get an out-of-memory error.

- Assure that the GPU is clear, e.g. no prior training/other model loaded in the same session.
- Reduce the batch-size.
- Use a different optimizer like SGD, Adam takes up some additional space.

Comment: GPU is clear. Why would batch-size and optimizer be a problem when it was none in the first training? My GPU has 80GB of memory. My 64 samples with 27MB + model & weights wont fill it

Comment: Theoretically it should be constant if you did not change anything. The main problem is always backpropagation that needs a ton of memory, it needs to store all forward states+parameter updates. If I recall correctly for the paramter weights does SGD+nesterov momentum need twice the amount of memory than standard SGD and Adam trice.